# Multiple criteria inside CASE WHEN statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

Here UserFlag, QtyAvailable and OrderStatus are three different columns and Im trying to create a two additional columns named "BackOrder Status" and "Shipped Status" in another view.

for BackOrder Status the condition would be

```
UserFlag =”On Order”
,UserFlag =”Sold Out”
, UserFlag =”On Order
, Sold Out”
, QtyAvailable=0
, OrderStatus =“Pending Fulfillment“ 
then it's a "BackOrder" ELSE "Not a BackOrder"
```

also, for Shipped Status the condition would be

```
Orders Shipped: OrderStatus =”Billed”
                , OrderStatus =”Partially Fulfilled”
                ,OrderStatus =”Pending Billing”
                , OrderStatus =”Pending Billing/ Partially Fulfilled”
 then it's "Shipped" ELSE "Not Shipped"
```

Please let me know if you come up with the query for this.Thanks in advance.

Attempt 1:

```
CASE 
  WHEN Userflag = 'On Order' AND QtyAvailable = '0' THEN 'BackOrder' 
  WHEN Userflag = 'Sold Out' AND QtyAvailable = '0' THEN 'BackOrder' 
  WHEN Userflag = 'On Order, Sold Out' AND QtyAvailable = '0' THEN 'BackOrder' 
  ELSE 'Not a Backorder' 
END
```

Attempt 2:

```
CASE 
  WHEN OrderStatus = 'Billed' THEN 'Order Shipped' 
  WHEN OrderStatus = 'Partially Fulfilled' THEN 'Order Shipped' 
  WHEN OrderStatus = 'Pending Billing' THEN 'Order Shipped' 
  WHEN OrderStatus = 'Pending Billing/Partially Fulfilled' THEN 'Order Shipped' 
  ELSE 'Not Shipped' 
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following:

> ```
> CREATE tABLE test(UserFlag varchar(100),QtyAvailable INT,OrderStatus VARCHAR(100))
> GO
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> CASE WHEN
> UserFlag IN ( 'On Order', 'Sold Out', 'On Order,Sold Out')
> AND 
> QtyAvailable = 0
> AND 
> OrderStatus = 'Pending Fulfillment' 
> then 'BackOrder'
> ELSE 'Not a BackOrder' 
> END AS [Orders Backorder]
> ,
>  CASE WHEN 
>       OrderStatus in ('Billed','Partially Fulfilled','Pending Billing','Pending Billing/ Partially Fulfilled')
>  THEN 'Shipped' ELSE 'Not Shipped' END AS [Orders Shipped]
> FROM test;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Orders Backorder | Orders Shipped
> :--------------- | :-------------
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=f106d99f1f0ac75cd1198201aebd1fc3)*

Comment: I did the same logic with the another similar thing which I'm working on. But, its showing an error saying "Operand datatype type varchar is invalid for divide operator". Attaching the query,           CASE WHEN UserFlag IN ('On Order' , 'Sold Out' , 'On Order,Sold Out') AND QtyAvailable = 0 AND OrderStatus IN ('Pending Fulfillment' , '’Billed’' , '’Pending Billing’' , '‘Partially Fulfilled’' , '‘Pending Billing' / 'Partially Fulfilled’' , '‘Closed’') THEN 'Not a BackOrder' ELSE 'BackOrder' END

Comment: It is quite hard to see the problem, but you can do a fiddle like the one at the end of my answer, where the problem can be hadled.

Comment: please [accept it](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I accepted. Thank you very much. Appreciate your help.